# Cannot find layout with laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am getting this error:

View [layouts.master] not found. (View: C:\xampp5\htdocs\laravel\laravel\resources\views\page.blade.php)

This is my master.blade.php:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
</head>

<body>
@section('sidebar')
    This is the master sidebar.
@show

<div class = "container">
    @yield('content')
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the page.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('sidebar')
    @parent
    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <h2>{{$name}}</h2>
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

And here is the relevant section of route:

```
Route::get('blade', function () {
    return view('page',array('name' => 'Random Name'));
});
```

Comment: Your master.blade location : view/layouts/master.blade

Comment: @Komal that's exactly the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put `master.blade.php` in this directory:

```
C:\xampp5\htdocs\laravel\laravel\resources\views\layouts
```

Or change path for the layout:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
```

to this:

```
@extends('master')
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
@extends('master')
@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('sidebar')
    @parent
    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <h2>{{$name}}</h2>
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```